# move last three elements from php array to first three

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to move the last three elements of an array, to become the first three elements. Is this possible? The array is variable depending on what page you're on, but it will look something like this:

```
Array
(
    [4] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 6
    [5] => 9
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 11
)
```

and I need it to be:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 9
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 11
    [4] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 6
)
```

Any help would be appreciated. The length of the array will also differ per page, so I'm not 100% sure how to go about it.

Comment: Try to pop and add those 3 items in a temporary array and then use array_unshift() to prepend them.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) is used to extract and insert sequences of elements in an array.

```
array_splice($array, 0, 0, array_splice($array, -3));
```

`array_splice($array, -3)` removes the last 3 elements of the array and returns that as an array. Then `array_splice($array, 0, 0, <that>)` inserts that array at the beginning of the array.

Note that this doesn't preserve keys of associative arrays, which seems to be necessary in your example. For that, you can use the `array_rotate` function defined in the [documentation notes](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php#105907)

```
function array_rotate($array, $shift) {
    if(!is_array($array) || !is_numeric($shift)) {
        if(!is_array($array)) error_log(__FUNCTION__.' expects first argument to be array; '.gettype($array).' received.');
        if(!is_numeric($shift)) error_log(__FUNCTION__.' expects second argument to be numeric; '.gettype($shift)." `$shift` received.");
        return $array;
    }
    $shift %= count($array); //we won't try to shift more than one array length
    if($shift < 0) $shift += count($array);//handle negative shifts as positive
    return array_merge(array_slice($array, $shift, NULL, true), array_slice($array, 0, $shift, true));
}
```

Comment: @LeanneSeawright It doesn't preserve keys. I've added a function that does.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `array_splice` doesnt preserve numeric keys (as seems to be the case according to the OP example). If you need that, this will work too:

```
$array1 = array
(
    4 => 1,
    2 => 2,
    3 => 6,
    5 => 9,
    0 => 10,
    1 => 11
);

$array2 = array_slice($array1, -3, 3, true)  + $array1;
```

And $array2 will be:

```
Array
(
    [5] => 9
    [0] => 10
    [1] => 11
    [4] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 6
)
```